# Find prime number which satisfies $p \in {\Bbb{{Q}_2}^{\times}}^2-{{\Bbb{Q}_2}^{\times}}^4$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

What is an minimal prime number $p$ which satisfies $p \in {\Bbb{{Q}_2}^{\times}}^2-{{\Bbb{Q}_2}^{\times}}^4$?

For $a \in \Bbb{Z}$, if $a≡1,3,4,7$mod8, then for each $a$, $\Bbb{Q}_2$ is $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{a})$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}_2,\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{3}),\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{5}),\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{7})$.

So I searched $p=17,41,73,\ldots$, which are primes which is $1\bmod8$.

For $p=17$, ${\rm ord}_2(f(3))=6>2{\rm ord}_2(f'(3))＝4$, thus by Hensel lemma, $17^{1/4}\in \Bbb{Q}_2$. So $p=17$ is not ok.

In such a way, can I find titled $p$ ? Or should I choose another way or computer ?
Computer method answer is also appreciated.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the multiplicative decomposition $\mathbf Z_2^\times = \{\pm 1\} \times (1 + 4\mathbf Z_2)$, so $(\mathbf Z_2^\times)^2 = (1 + 4\mathbf Z_2)^2$. Using the $2$-adic exponential,
$$
1 + 4\mathbf Z_2 = \exp(4\mathbf Z_2) \Longrightarrow (1+4\mathbf Z_2)^2 = \exp(8\mathbf Z_2).
$$
The $2$-adic exponential and logarithm are isometries between $4\mathbf Z_2$ and $1 + 4\mathbf Z_2$, so $\exp(8\mathbf Z_2) = 1 + 8\mathbf Z_2$. Similarly,
$$
(1+4\mathbf Z_2)^4 = \exp(16\mathbf Z_2) = 1 + 16\mathbf Z_2.
$$
So the $u \in \mathbf Z_2^\times$ that are squares and not fourth powers are exactly the $u$ where $u \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ and $u \not\equiv 1 \bmod 16$, which is equivalent to $u \equiv 9 \bmod 16$.  The first few such $u$ that are prime numbers are $41$, $73$, $89$, $137$, and $233$.

Answer (score 2):

The squares in $\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times}$ are exactly the elements of the form $1+8u$ with $u \in \mathbb{Q}_2$. Hence such an element is a fourth power iff the square root of $1+8u$ is itself of the form $1+8u'$.

Let's see if we can do this. The square root of $1+8u$ can be obtained by evaluating the binomial series
$$
(1+8u)^{1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{n} (8u)^n = 1+4u-8u^2+\ldots
$$
Now the $2$-adic valuation of the binomial coefficient $\binom{1/2}{n}$ equals $-n-\operatorname{ord}_2(n!)$, which by [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) equals
$$
-n-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{8} \right\rfloor-\ldots \geq -n \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\ldots\right)=-2n,
$$
which means that the coefficient of the $u^n$ term in the binomial formula has
valuation $\geq n$ (this also shows that the series is convergent by the way). In particular, none of the terms of degree $3$ or higher will contribute anything to the sum modulo $8$.

We may therefore conclude that the square root of $1+8u$ is congruent to $1+4u$ modulo $8$, and this number is therefore itself a square if and only if $u=2u'$ for some $u'$. Hence the fourth powers are those elements which are of the form $1+16u'$, and the squares which are not fourth powers are those elements which are of the form $9+16u'$. In particular, the (rational) primes $41$ and $73$ would be examples of such elements.

Comment: Is every integer which is 4-th power in $\Bbb{Q}_2$ is $1+16a$($a \in \Bbb{Z}$ )?

Comment: @masquerade Not every integer, but every integer with valuation $0$ is of that form yes. You can also get this result directly by expanding $(1+2x)^4$, which would give a more elementary solution to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your really helpful answer. This is irrelevant to this question, so you don't have responsibility to answer this question, but do you know some criterion integer $a$ is 4-th power in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{2})$ ?

Comment: What I want to know is, in $p=3,5,11,13,19,29,37,43,51,53,・・・$, which prime is 4-th power in $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{2})$. Can I solve this kind of problem by hand ? I may repost this in another post.

Comment: @masquerade I would recommend asking this as a separate question. In any case I wouldn't know this off the top of my head. For $\mathbb{Q}_2$ the question was made easier because the question is really about $\mathbb{Z}_2$, whose quotients are the familiar finite rings $\mathbb{Z}/2^k \mathbb{Z}$. However for $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{2})$, I would first need to figure out what its ring of integers is, and how I can get a handle on its finite quotients. This might be much more difficult, but I would have to dig down a lot more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help.